# WCF .NET Service being consumed by Android returning "No Action header was found with namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing'

Tags: c#, android, web-services, wcf, android-ksoap2

I have a WCF .NET webservice that is being consumed by an Android application. We are using KSoap2 library and have gotten as far as we could by searching and looking for answers.

This is our Android code:

```
static final String NAMESPACE = "https://services.ostara.com/StellarService/";
static final String URL = "https://services.ostara.com/StellarService/StellarService.svc";
static final String SOAP_ACTION = "https://services.ostara.com/StellarService/getNextBagNumber";
static final String METHOD_NAME = "getNextBagNumber";

SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo info = new PropertyInfo();
        info.setName("apiKey");
        info.setValue("16bb9027-4a49-4d24-899a-xxxxx");
        info.setType(String.class);
        soapObject.addProperty(info);



        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new 
        SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

Wondering what the issue could be here and why we are getting the following error:
No Action header was found with namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' for the given message.

Comment: Hi, im facing the same issue, did you resolve it?